# jquery multiselect doesnt work on dynamically added element into html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I dynamically create element using js calling js function like this

```
function addElement(){
    var counter = 1;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.id='dynamicdiv' + counter;
    newdiv.innerHTML += "<select class=\"checkedValues\" multiple=\"multiple\"><option value=\"1\">One</option><option value=\"2\">Two</option></select>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;
}
```

on page load [jquery multi select effect](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/03/jquery-multiselect-dropdown-list-with-checkboxes.html) is applied

```
$(function() {
   $('.checkedValues').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
});
```

This effect doesnt work on this dynamically injected element. How to apply it?

Comment: stop and think about it...how can the code transform something that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: naturally, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call it again after injecting element, because your first code is just getting executing once when **DOM** is loaded, and you are adding elements to DOM via js after DOM is loaded:

```
function addElement(){
    var counter = 1;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.id='dynamicdiv' + counter;
    newdiv.innerHTML += "<select class=\"checkedValues\" multiple=\"multiple\"><option value=\"1\">One</option><option value=\"2\">Two</option></select>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;

    $(newdiv).find('.checkedValues').multiselect({
     includeSelectAllOption: true
   });  // call it here again
}
```

Comment: should really only target the new element, not the whole class

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the code on the new element. The code does not magically listen for new elements to be added to the page.

```
var counter = 1;

function addElement() {
  var newdiv = $("<div/>", {
    id: 'dynamicdiv' + counter
  });
  var select = $("<select class=\"checkedValues\" multiple=\"multiple\"><option value=\"1\">One</option><option value=\"2\">Two</option></select>");
  newDiv.append(select);
  $("#" + divName).append(newdiv);
  select.multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
  });
  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the multiselect to recently added item after appending:

```
 function addElement(){
  var counter = 1;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.id='dynamicdiv' + counter;
  newdiv.innerHTML += "<select class=\"checkedValues\" multiple=\"multiple\"><option value=\"1\">One</option><option value=\"2\">Two</option></select>";
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  counter++;

  $('#'+divName+' .checkedValues:last').multiselect({
     includeSelectAllOption: true
  }); 
}
```