# Select2 autocomplete - Ajax request call controller only at startup

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, jquery-select2

I'va got a Select2 4.0.0 plugin on a  field on an ASP.NET MVC project.

HTML:

```
<select id="MotosAccepteesID" class="form-control" multiple></select>
```

This is how I initialize the field and the Ajax query: (mostly come from Select2 4.0.0 documentation)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var $element = $('#MotosAccepteesID').select2({
            placeholder: 'Taper au moins 2 caractères',
            minimumInputLength: 2
        });

        var $request = $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ListePartielleMotos", "Motos", null)',
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 250,
            type: "GET"
        });

        $request.then(function (data) {
            // This assumes that the data comes back as an array of data objects
            // The idea is that you are using the same callback as the old `initSelection`

            for (var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
                var item = data[d];

                // Create the DOM option that is pre-selected by default
                var option = new Option(data.text, data.id, true, true);

                // Append it to the select
                $element.append(option);
            }

            // Update the selected options that are displayed
            $element.trigger('change');
        });

    });
```

And this have to call an action in a controller:

```
public ActionResult ListePartielleMotos(string q)
    {
        // Breakpoint here, reached only once, at startup
        MotoContext mc = new MotoContext();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(q))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var suggestions = from s in mc.Motos
                          select new
                          {
                              id = s.ID,
                              value = s.Marque.Nom + " " + s.Modele + " (" + s.Cylindree + ")"
                          };
        var motoList = suggestions.ToList().Where(n => n.value.ToLower().Contains(q.ToLower())).Take(20);

        return Json(motoList.Select(m => new
        {
            id = m.id,
            text = m.value
        }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Ok now the problem:

When I access the web page, the controller is called (My breakpoint is reached) with a null parameter. Ok.

But then, when I write something in the field, nothing happen. I see no error in javascript.

Do someone have an idea about it? It's been two days and I'm about to cry blood.

n.b.: I also install JQuery UI to test their autocomplete feature for anotther field on another page, maybe an incompatibilty issue?

Thx!

**Update**

When I set a breakpoint in the javascript code, on

```
var $request = $.ajax({
```

(using Chrome), the breakpoint is reached only at startup too.

Im' a beginner in javascript and JQuery. Maybe this code shouldn't be in

```
$(document).ready(function () { });
```

Comment: is your select rerendered via partial view? if thats the case you have to reinitialize select2 plugin in ajax success

Comment: this is similar question, but different plugin using:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439239/jquery-multiselect-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-added-element-into-html-page/30439268#30439268

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I initialize my select again right after "$element.trigger('change');" but still nothing. I think the problem is before that, since my controller isn't even called.

Comment: You haven't added an `ajax` property to your select2 options... https://select2.github.io/options.html#ajax

Comment: @JamieDunstan My bad, you're right. That's what happen when you copy/paste something without thinking...